# Looping a walk animation

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

If I were to animate a few steps of a walk going forward and using IK to keep the feet in place as the body moves overtop, is there any way you can loop this animation so the character keeps walking forward? Without him returning to his original spot every time?

Answer (score 1):

Loops are generally programmed "in place", having the feets sliding on the floor, and then a forward motion is applied to the whole armature, to simulate a real walking. If you don't want to follow this scheme, you will have to to set keyframes to have your character "jump" forward every frame your animation "jumps" backward. If the loop works the amount of movemente will be always the same, so the programming will be easy, even with long walks.